Seeing previous logged in user data in ProfileWindow after log in other user
In my app I have a ProfileWindow component where user can see its data and update it. I use React Query to fetch user data from Firebase Firestore. When I register new user for instance and navigate to ProfileWindow I see data of last logged in user for 1 sec and only after that current logged in user data displays. Whats the matter and how to fix.
Hook:
const fetchUser = async (): Promise<IUser | undefined> => {
  const userUid = auth.currentUser?.uid;
  if (!userUid) return;

  const userDocRef = doc(db, "users", userUid);
  const userDoc = await getDoc(userDocRef);

  console.log("uid", userUid);
  console.log("data", userDoc.data());

  if (!userDoc.exists()) {
    throw new Error("User document does not exist");
  }

  return userDoc.data() as IUser;
};

export const useGetUser = () => {
  const { data, refetch } = useQuery({
    queryKey: ["user"],
    queryFn: fetchUser,
  });

  return {
    user: data,
    refetch,
  };
};

ProfileWindow:
export const ProfileWindow = () => {
  const theme = useTheme();
  const { setModal } = useModal();
  const { user, refetch } = useGetUser();
  const {
    register,
    handleSubmit,
    trigger,
    reset,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm<IFormData>({
    defaultValues: {
      uid: "",
      name: "",
      bio: "",
    },
  });

  console.log("data inside component", user);

  useEffect(() => {
    if (user) {
      console.log("trigger");
      reset({
        uid: user?.uid,
        name: user?.name,
        bio: user?.bio,
      });
    }
  }, [user, reset]);

  return (
    <WindowContainer>
    ...
    </WindowContainer>
  );
};


Welcome to SO. Did you perform troubleshooting by stepping through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected? If you did, please include your findings - what line isn't working? Where does the code start to fail? Please update the question.
